# Does Android support log2

Tags: android, c, android-x86

Does android supports log2 ?
I already find that android doesnt support long double.

When i tried to compile cdce3.c  I received following error:

```
g++.dg/cdce3.C: In function 'void mlog2f(int)':
g++.dg/cdce3.C:87: error: 'log2f' was not declared in this scope
g++.dg/cdce3.C: In function 'void mlog2(int)':
g++.dg/cdce3.C:87: error: 'log2' was not declared in this scope
g++.dg/cdce3.C: In function 'void olog2f(int)':
g++.dg/cdce3.C:108: error: 'log2f' was not declared in this scope
g++.dg/cdce3.C: In function 'void olog2(int)':
g++.dg/cdce3.C:108: error: 'log2' was not declared in this scope
```

---

Part of cdce3.c source code:

```
#define DEF_MATH_FUNC(prefix, name) NI void prefix##name##f (int x) \
{ \
  float yy = name##f ((float) x); \
  STORE_RESULT; \
} \
NI void prefix##name (int x) \
{ \
  double yy = name ((double)x); \
  STORE_RESULT; \
}
#endif
.........
DEF_MATH_FUNC (m,log2)
DEF_MATH_FUNC (o,log2)
```

find full [source code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/NetBSD/src/external/gpl3/gcc/dist/gcc/testsuite/g++.dg/cdce3.C) here.

Comment: `log2(x) = log(x) / log(2)`, so you can easily roll your own (compute `log(2)` first).

Comment: Thank you, i remember it from school math program. But i can not do it, because all i can it change some compilation keys. Or find another magical way for supporting log2 function. I am interested in supporting the log2 in Android by default. As i already said maybe with some magical keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Android doesn't support log2 function by default. Because i don't found nowhere in source codes determining of this function.

Answer (score 8):

Your magical way is here. I've tested it and worked:

```
make CXXFLAGS="-Dlog2\(x\)=\(log\(x\)/log\(2\)\)"
```

faster computation:

```
make CXXFLAGS="-Dlog2\(x\)=\(log\(x\)*1.4426950408889634\)"
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 1/log(2) value be be actually 3.32192809489?