# Qt: Undefined reference to atof, log2 & log2f on android linking to FFmpeg

Tags: android, c++, qt, ffmpeg, math.h

Trying to build my **Qt application** for **android** linking to **FFmpeg**.

I get the following linker errors on android.

```
libavformat/hls.c:783: error: undefined reference to 'atof'
libavcodec/ffv1enc.c:476: error: undefined reference to 'log2'
libavcodec/imc.c:472: error: undefined reference to 'log2f'
```

Following is the list of libraries I trying to link for *FFmpeg*.

```
-lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavfilter -lswresample -lavdevice -lpostproc -lm -lgnustl_static
```

**What am I missing in the linker options?**

I have also set the following to :

```
CONFIG += c++14
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -std=c++1y
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -std=c++1y
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571399/android-ndk-cant-find-atof-function

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41079462/192373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strictly not related to Qt and happens only because those functions are not defined in Android, as discussed in [Does Android support log2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080118/does-android-support-log2) and [Android ndk can't find atof function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571399/android-ndk-cant-find-atof-function), among other places.

You either have to define those functions before including FFmpeg headers or find a library that does this for you.

Comment: They should be in *libm* which he is linking in

Comment: Yes, they should, but unfortunately they are not implemented on Android for some reason. They are in the headers, just not in the .so.